# Is it possible to manipulate Google Analytics to show more visitors (possible scam found)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

recently I found a Website on flippa where the googleanalytics statistics did not fully match up with the other data (they were to high but verified)

For personal interest I tried to modify the G. Analytics code to see if I could fake the Analytics report:

This is what I got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19629541-9']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =   true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +     '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

}

</script>
```

Please notice this part of the script          "for (i=0;i<=10;i++)" i<=10 means that for every visitor that visits your site, it counts as 10 page views and should actually puts your bounce rate below 1% so it looks like people are staying on your site. I tried it and it worked.

The thing is I was not able to manipulate the amount of visitors nor the amount of unique visitors displayed on the G. Analytics report.

For educational purposes could theses statistics be manipulated

PS aktually flippa verifies G. Analytics Report by making you sent a report to them through the G. Analytics Dashboard via email

Comment: how about: http://jsfiddle.net/gW5XM/

Answer (score 4):

GA is something amazing tool which can be modified as per the website activity,  The flexibility on code is made to capture the data as per the user choice, The code is actually is used to control the bounce rate as per the website, the default value sometimes calculate wrong data. So Chriswede, it is not scam or manipulation by GA but a flexibility from Google to generate the Data Accurately as per the User.

Answer (score 1):

You manipulating your own visitor data. You could've manipulated them directly on dashboard. It is not like you give your login/password to somebody else to prove how cool is your site, right?

Comment: aktually flippa verifies it by msking you sent a report to them via email

Comment: Too bad for them to trust data that never guaranteed to be precise instead of collecting their own and using fraud detection.

Comment: sry but have u ever used flippa there are excellent in collecting all available data and making the dudilegance process easier. Would really like to here of a better system which is still affordable

Comment: There's exactly two cases: you modify data that you yourself consume in the end (maybe post-processed, but it doesn't matter). In this case nobody cares what and how you do with you own data. Second case: you falsify data for somebody else's consumption - this is bad. What case are you dealing with?

Comment: I belive the second and I would like to see a sample script so that I can take aktion against it --> knowledge is power ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `_gaq.push([_setDomainName, '.domain.com']);` and `_gaq.push([_setDomainName, 'domain.com']);` alternatively & randomly in your loop (before `_trackPageview`) you can also inflate the actual number of visitors / unique visitors.

Comment: so like: <script type="text/javascript">

var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19629541-9']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push([_setDomainName, '.domain.com']); _gaq.push([_setDomainName, 'domain.com']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =   true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +     '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

}
</script>